# How to handle List<T> that's stored in an object

Tags: c#, generics

I am working on adding some logging to my program to help with tracking function calls and parameters. To do this I have created a function that takes a parameter array of objects and then at runtime I determine the type to define how each object should be handled.  The issue I'm running into is if I have a List of SqlParameter in parameters[1], how do I generically handle this so I don't need to define every type of List I can potentially pass in?  For each item in the List I am just going to call ToString so I don't have any need to know the actual type.  I've tried below to convert it to a list of object but that is failing.

```
public static string LogParameters(params object[] parameters)
    {
        string returnValue = "\n";

        if (parameters != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
            {
                if (parameters[i] == null)
                {
                    returnValue += $"---->null null\n";
                }
                else if (parameters[i].GetType().IsGenericType)
                {
                    // error is happening on this line
                    List<object> objects = (List<object>)parameters[i];

                    returnValue += GetLogParameterTypeText(objects);

                    for (int x = 0; x < objects.Count; x++)
                    {
                        returnValue += GetLogParameterTypeText(objects[x], "----");
                    }
                }
                else if (parameters[i].GetType().IsArray)
                {
                    object[] objects = (object[])parameters[i];

                    returnValue += GetLogParameterTypeText(objects);

                    for (int x = 0; x < objects.Length; x++)
                    {
                        returnValue += GetLogParameterTypeText(objects[x], "----");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    returnValue += GetLogParameterTypeText(parameters[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
```

Here is a sample of how the function is called

```
Log.Information($"{LogParameters(fieldName, dataType, fieldValue, panelName)}");
```

Comment: Is the `T` of `List<T>` ever a value type such as `int`?

Comment: @phoog I'm trying to build it to handle any situation so yes that is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `List<T>`, use `IEnumerable<T>`. Unlike a list, enumerables allow for type variance, so `List<string>` does actually implement `IEnumerable<object>`, while it does *not* implement either `List<object>` or `IList<object>`.

For bonus points, arrays also implement `IEnumerable`, so you can change your logic to something like

```
if (parameters[i] is IEnumerable<object> enumerable)
{
  returnValue += GetLogParameterTypeText(enumerable);

  foreach (var object in enumerable) 
  {
    returnValue += GetLogParameterTypeText(object, "----");
  }
}
```

You might also want to consider using `StringBuilder` to build the return value; concatenating strings requires a lot more allocations.

Comment: If the list's type argument is a value type this still wont work.  Since the goal is to call `ToString()` on each item in the list, it's simpler to use `System.Collections.IEnumerable` instead of `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @phoog To handle the situation you mentioned I added `elseif (parameters[i] is System.Collections.IEnumerable enumerableValue)` Thank you both for your help!